# How to access calendar.readonly oauth-2.0 service from an IoT device?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, iot, headless

I want to access private calendar content in read-only, from an IoT device.

This device is programmed in C, and has full REST capabilities meaning that I am able to build HTTP requests in the device, but I don't have any way of interracting with it (no screen, no keyboard).

I found a way to do this (using google data api), but it is completely deprecated.

What is the procedure to follow for doing this?

Comment: By checking the GData API Directory, it says here that Calendar is now replaced by [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/#basic_concepts). You can also see here, on how to [authorize request with Oath 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth). Check also this [tutorial](https://blog.tsheets.com/2014/business-help/using-oauth-2-0-to-authenticate-with-rest-ful-web-apis) for more information and if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I read the tutorial, but I doubt it is applicable to my case.
I need a kind of server-to-server authentication scheme, but without interaction from the user, as it is a device which access google calendar api.